# Why am I able to use variables inside a null reference?

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton, unity-game-engine, inner-classes

I'm not really sure how to describe it exactly so let me show you what is going on.

I have a `PlayerControls` script which looks like this (note: I stripped everything except for the necessities).

```
namespace Player.Controls {
    internal class PlayerControls: MonoBehaviour {
        public bool IsClimbing { get; private set; } = false;
        public bool IsGrounded { get; private set; } = false;
    }
}
```

These variables are set in this class depending if the player is climbing/touching the ground. This script resides on the "Player" `GameObject` in the scene.

I have another script called `PlayerController`which looks like this

```
using Player.Controls;
public class PlayerController: Singleton<PlayerController> {
    internal PlayerStats stats = new PlayerStats();
    //PlayerStats nested class (see below)
}
```

The `Singleton` class only checks if the generic type is `null`, if it is, it will use `FindObjectOfType` to get an instance. This script also resides on the "Player" `GameObject`.

Inside the `PlayerController` class, I have a nested class called `PlayerStats`. It looks like this

```
internal class PlayerStats : PlayerControls {
    public new bool IsClimbing { get { return base.IsClimbing; } }
    public new bool IsGrounded { get { return base.IsGrounded; } }
}
```

Notice this nested class in inheriting from `PlayerControls`.



The idea is that the `PlayerControls` class in inaccessible to all other classes except for `PlayerController`, and any information I want to obtain regarding the player can be obtained by getting the player's instance (via the singleton) and accessing the `PlayerStats` variable.

For example, assuming the variable inside `Singleton` which holds the instance is called `Instance`, one could do `PlayerController.Instance.stats.IsClimbing;` Everything works as expected, except for one thing.

In the `Awake` method of the `PlayerController` class, I do this

```
private void Awake() {
    Debug.LogFormat("In PlayerController Awake(). Is PlayerController.stats null? {0}",
    (stats.Equals(null) ? "Yes" : "No"));

    Debug.LogFormat("IsClimbing : {0}", stats.IsClimbing);
}
```

In the output window, it prints
`In PlayerController Awake(). Is PlayerController.stats null? Yes`
`IsClimbing : False`

If I also put the same `IsClimbing` debug in the `Update()` method, the value is correct for when I start climbing.

So, finally, my question, how can I access the variables of the `PlayerStats` class with the `stats` variable if `stats` is `null`? I thought it may have been somehow calling straight to the `PlayerControls` properties, so I changed their names, removed the `new` inside of `PlayerStats` and even put a debug statement inside one of the properties inside `PlayerStats`, and it definitely gets called. For example,
`public bool IsClimbing { get { Debug.Log("Called IsClimbing inside PlayerStats.");  return base.Climbing; } }`

If it is getting called and working properly, how can it be `null`? I asked my professor and he doesn't seem to know why either. What is really going on here?

**Edit:**

As requested, the `Singleton` class:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T>: MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour {
    private static T instance;

    public static T Instance {
        get {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = FindObjectOfType<T>();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is an image of the console output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsuKf.png)

Comment: Did you write the "Singleton" class? If so, can we see it?

Comment: It is now included.

Comment: did you override the equals method by any chance? can you put `stats.ReferenceEquals(null)` instead of `stats.Equals(null)` and check if the result is the same?

Comment: If `stats` was `null` then `stats.Equals(...)` would fail with a null reference exception. If you're just checking for null, the why not just use `stats == null`?

Comment: I'm not overriding `Equals` to my knowledge. When I use `ReferenceEquals` it says it is **not** null. Why is this?

Comment: When I did `stats == null`, the result was the same as `stats.Equals(null)`.

Comment: Yes, because `stats` isn't null.

Comment: for me it looks like your equals method had been overridden somewhere (may be in a parent class?). you can use `ReferenceEquals` since it cannot be overridden, or try to use `==` and see what will happen (note that `==` might be overridden as well)

Comment: but yes, as @DavidG said, your stats is not null, so you not getting any kind of exception.

Comment: Does Unity override `Equals` or `==` for `MonoBehaviors`? That's the only way either could have gotten overridden. If my `stats` is truly not `null`, why is `Equals` and `==` saying it is while `ReferenceEquals` is saying it is not?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you swap the two lines, so that you first print "IsClimbing", then check for null?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter which I print I do first.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?  Your question is "How can you access those properties if the instance is null?"  The answer is you can't.  You will get a NullReferenceException even if the Equals method is overridden.  The original post states you are calling a method called Awake that exists on PlayerController and PlayerController instantiates an instance of PlayerStats.  By definition, your stats instance will never be null under the conditions you have outlined....but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The question is why `Equals` and `==` is saying it is `null` when I am able to access the variables (proving that it is not `null`).

Answer (score 2):

Digging around on the Unity forums [it appears that the `Equals` method has been overridden](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/586188/view.html) (on [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) which [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) eventually derives from) which is why comparing a [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) to `null` is not giving you what you might expect. The answer I link to suggests code like this is more appropriate:

```
stats == null || stats.Equals(null)
```

Comment: You may add a possible reason for this behaviour from the page you linked: If a Unity game object gets destroyed, it is marked as destroyed, but it still does exist. You can access the object and each of its members, but if someone checks for the existence of the object, Unity wants to tell them, that it does not exist (and evaluates the null-check to `true`).

Comment: But why are the overloaded `Equals` and `==` returning null in the first place?